# How can create a new table in database if the table does not exist (c#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqldataadapter

Here is my code, it works when the database has the table "UserInformation"

```
public bool Save()
{
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var adapter = new UserInformationTableAdapter())
                    {
                        adapter.Connection = connection;
                        adapter.Transaction = transaction;

                        var table = new HelloDataSet.UserInformationDataTable();
                        HelloDataSet.UserInformationRow row = table.NewUserInformationRow();
                        row.UserName = userName;
                        row.Password = password;
                        row.Brithday = brithday;
                        table.Rows.Add(row);
                        adapter.Update(table);

                        transaction.Commit();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
}
```

However, when there is no table in the database, it will not create the "UserInformation" table in the database, it will jump to "catch" exception in line "adapter.Update(table);"

So my question is how can I create a new table in database if there is no "UserInformation" table in it. In addition, if the database already has the table "UserInformation" can I add a new column "Position" in that table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you trying to insert rows into a table that may not exist? Are you wanting the database server to automatically create a table with a specific field structure if the table is not present? (Why would the table not be there?) I'd suggest creating the table using a `CREATE TABLE` command or using an interactive tool like SQL Server Management Studio. Also, you don't mention what kind of database you're working with. Tagging this question accordingly will improve the relevance of the answers.

Comment: I want database server to automatically create the table. The reason is, I am going to allow user to choose the database, so if user switch to a new database my application should be able to create that table in the new database.

Comment: You're going to have to create a script or series of SQL statements that your program executes. Stored procedures or triggers are out because if the database is new, it won't have tables or any code to create the tables. I'd check for the existence of one of your tables then ask the user "initialize tables for (application name)?" and if the user says yes, run your script or set of `CREATE TABLE` SQL statements.

Comment: "**her code can let the database side automatically create the [tables]**" I submit that somewhere between your friend, you and me, something critical is being omitted here. By *automatically* I'm thinking she's got a set of `CREATE TABLE` statements that take care of business. Ask her for more details.

Comment: Sorry, I did not finish the last comment and press send by accidentally. However, you got the point, and thank hou so much for comment my question. I am going to ask my friend today or later, as long as I got the answer, I will tell you.

Comment: @BobKaufman I had a quick chat with my friend. Basically, you are right, I cannot let the database automatically create a new table without 'CREATE TABLE' statement. What she did is use data manager to create a '_DB_Schema' table for her, every time when she make the changes in one database, she will increase the version of the '_DB_Schema', so when the application runs in other database, it will check the '_DB_Schema' version, if it is below the application version, the data manager will update the change automatically for the new database. I am still trying to finger out the details.

Comment: @BobKaufman I posted an answer for my question, and you are totally right. My friend write a framework to do what you told me before. Now problem solved. Thank you so much for answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer and want to share it out. First, I have to say that I put my question in a wrong way. What I really want is I have an application, and this application is connected with a database. However, I am allowed user to switch database. So, when the user switch to a new database I would like the application copy the entire database structure (not including the data) from the old one to the new one. Also, if I make some change (could be add a new column for one or more table, or add another new table) for the database in my application code, I would like every other database know the updates and make the same change by running my new application code.

---

So, here is my solution. I write a framework called "SchemaManager." It will create an additional table in each database, this table contains the version of the database. So, every time when I run my application the "SchemaManager" will check my hard code database version number with the database version number, if my hard code database version number is greater than the database version number, the "SchemaManager" will check the change and do the update for me.

---

I know my solution is not the best, but this is what I did. If anyone have anyother solution, please share with me and other people.